# Transfer Session Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript, session-state, session-variables

I am trying to pass a vbscript session variable to my c# page.
Upon research I found this page:

[Transfer Session Variables from Classic ASP to ASP.NET](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021207.asp)

I don't know how to change my

```
Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TypeID"]);
```

to read in the session variable in the same manner as from the code provided in the link above(pasted below:)

```
 <TITLE>ASPNETPage1.aspx</TITLE>
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<script runat=server>
// We iterate through the Form collection and assign the names and values
// to ASP.NET session variables! We have another Session Variable, "DestPage"
// that tells us where to go after taking care of our business...
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
for(int i=0;i<Request.Form.Count;i++)
{
Session[Request.Form.GetKey(i)]=Request.Form[i].ToString();
}
Server.Transfer(Session["DestPage"].ToString(),true);
}
</script>
```

==============================================================================

```
<TITLE>FinalPage.aspx</TITLE>
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<script runat=server>
// This page is just a "proof of concept page"...

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
Response.Write("Shared Session Variable Names/Values between Classic ASP and ASP.NET:<BR>");
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Contents.Count; i++) 
{ 
Response.Write("Assigned to \"" +Session.Keys[i].ToString()+"\"");  
Response.Write(" Value: "+ Session[i].ToString() +"<BR>");
} 
}
</script>
```

Update:
Code for where session variable is called on C# page:

```
 private void FillGrid()
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bdsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                Con.Open();
                Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["TypeID"]);
                Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(intresortID);
                Label4.Visible = true;
                DateTime startdate;
                startdate = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);

                Int32 ed = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
                DateTime enddate;
                enddate = startdate.AddDays(ed);

                string str = "SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT tblAvail.dtm as Dtm, tblResortsRooms.strRoomType as strRoomType, tblResortsRooms.strDescription as strDescription, tblAvail.intQty as intQty, tblAvail.curPrice as curPrice, tblResortsRooms.intWSCode  as intWSCode FROM tblAvail INNER JOIN tblResortsRooms ON tblAvail.intResortID = tblResortsRooms.intResortID AND tblAvail.strRoomType = tblResortsRooms.strRoomType WHERE (tblResortsRooms.curRecRate > 0) AND (tblAvail.intResortID = @intResortID) and (tblAvail.dtm between @startdate and @enddate) ORDER BY tblResortsRooms.strRoomType";
                SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Con);
                sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intResortID", intresortID);
                sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
                sdr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sdr.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                    Button2.Visible = true;
                }




            }

        }
```

Can somebody please show me how?

Comment: try to use this method, it seems to be different http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30723/Handle-session-variable-problems-between-classic-A

Comment: If you are trying to transfer variable from VBScript to C# code behind, it means you are doing some thing wrong.
I am interested in knowing few more details from you which could help me to give you a better solution. Is in your project a mix of asp and asp.net technology or you are using VBScript as client side scripting language ?

Comment: I have a vbscript page when my user clicks on a button on the vbscript  page it opens up a c# page to which the session variable gets passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line is that a session variable in Classical ASP is not available to ASP.Net (regardless of the language used). You will need to make that value available to the ASP.Net page via a query string or form that gets posted back to the ASP.Net page. So a suggested solution is to pass the value (which apparently is in a session variable in the classical ASP page) via a query string to the ASP.Net page. Then on the ASP.Net page retrieve the query string value and do whatever you want with it.

I hope I haven't missed the point. But bottom line is there is no interaction between session variables in Classical ASP and ASP.Net because they use completely different frameworks and engines.

Comment: Are you saying that I should have it as a query string on ASP and let it retrieve query string on .net? I am familiar with the retrieve as a query string in .net but how do I make it a query string to go to .net from the classic asp page?Would you happen to have an example?

Comment: Yes exactly. So if within ASP (classical) you generate a link to the ASP.Net page and within that link you pass the information (which apparently in your situation is held in a session variable in ASP) via the query string then in ASP.Net you could easily retrieve the value like this:

`string MyValue = Request.QueryString["QueryStringItem"].ToString();`

The link would simply be something like this:

http://domain/ASPPage.Net?QueryStringItem=MySessionVariableValue

I hope this helps.

Michael

Comment: I don't quite get your suggestion. Would something like this be the same as what you are saying? in my vbscript page: TypeID=Session("TypeID") and in my aspx page:  Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TypeID"]);

Comment: and my url that points to my aspx page is like this: http://localhost/AvRates/Availability.aspx?intresortID=<%=TypeID%>

Comment: Yes exactly. As you have illustrated here you can concatenate onto the link to the ASP.Net page using a variety of methods including of course the example you have shown where you directly Response.Write it into the link. It seems like you are happy with this approach. Michael

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to follow Microsoft path http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx

Comment: While this option looks good to me it won't work in this scenario.  From the linked page: "This solution will not support an existing ASP application that stores a COM object in the Session object. In this case, a custom marshaler is needed to serialize/deserialize the states in order to use the custom session object."

Comment: @Peter simple solution don't store COM objects inside the Session object. There is no need to do this and it just adds overheads.

Answer (score 1):

First off, in "ASPNETPage1.aspx" you are copying the whole `Form` collection to `Session` variables - which is absolutely unnecessary, since you are already preserving it with the `Server.Transfer`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w.aspx

Secondly, in "FinalPage.aspx", instead of iterating through the whole `Session` state, you can access that same `Form` collection directly through the `Page.PreviousPage` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

**UPDATE:** wow, my bad there, I really thought you were talking about `Visual Basic` (as your question title, article link and sample code would all suggest) and not `VBScript` - which is a **client** language, so you would need an equivalent of `JavaScript PageMethod` or a `WebService` (never used `VBScript`, so don't know if it supports those things) to access the `Session` state on the **server**

my corrections for your code sample still stand, offcourse

**UPDATE 2:** `PageMethod` or a `WebService` is implemented by the **server** language (`Visual Basic` or `C#`) on the server, and `VBScript` or `JavaScript` (both **client** languages) are just used to access it from the client - you need to learn to differentiate between server and client languages...

So, for the final time, are you using `Visual Basic` or `VBScript`? And post your original code if you expect any meaningful help from others.

Comment: My session variable is in vbscript and I want to access it from my c# page. Is that the same as your answer is saying?

Comment: If you can give me a sample code for what you are advising would be great. I have not used javascript pagemethod before

Answer (score 0):

No experience with C# but based on my classic ASP experience id should be

```
Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[i]);
```

or if you know the name of the key, TypeID in this case, no need for the For loop

```
Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form("TypeID"));
```

If this doens't work, try splitting up and logging

```
for(int i=0;i<Request.Form.Count;i++)
{
  loggingRoutine(Request.Form.GetKey(i) + "=" + Request.Form[i].ToString());
}
```

(as i said, i'm no C# guy, just to get you an idea)

The Sessionvariables are only to remember values between page refreshes and between other pages, if you read the form directly in the first .ASPX there is no need for them.

Comment: Thanks for that @peter: I am attempting your second option. My intresortid is a parameter for my select command so I probably can't use the 3rd option....

Comment: I have updated my question to show where I am calling the session variable. It comes as 0

Comment: does Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["TypeID"]); give you 0 ? and what with String intresortID = Request.Form["TypeID"]; ? do you want to set or read a sessionvariable there ?

Comment: honestly you lost me, it's not clear to me. you'd better make a testcase with only the bare minimum to transfer your variable and publish these files instead