# How to pass the entire contents of Classic ASP session to .net code?

Tags: asp-classic

I know the drill about how to call .net code from a Classic ASP site (Server.CreateObject, gacutil, and all the rest).  I'm talking about invoking a .net DLL from VBScript code.  (This has nothing to do with ASP.net)

What I would like to know is, how can I pass the contents of the entire Classic ASP session to the .net code.  I think that I would like to pass `Session.Contents` to the .net code, but I don't know how to write an interface that would accept that object.

Bonus points if you can also tell me how to pass the entire contents of `Request.Form` as well as `ASPError` objects.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but did you see this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx  or this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679572/transfer-session-variables

Comment: I am familiar with using SQL to share session between classic ASP and ASP.net, but in this case, there is no ASP.net session, just a classic ASP session, and I need to access the contents of that session from a method in a .net library invoked by the ASP code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean `Set invokedNetDLL = CreateObject("MyNamespace.MyType")` when you say "invoking a .net DLL from VBScript code", I'd try the following:

```
<%
    Dim key
    Dim serializedSession
    Dim invokedNetDLL

    For Each key in Session
        serializedSession = key & "=" & Session(key) & "&"
    Next

    'Trim last &
    serializedSession = Left(serializedSession, Len(serializedSession) - 1)

    Set invokedNetDLL = CreateObject("MyNamespace.MyType")
    invokedNetDLL.MyMethod(serializedSession)

%>
```

As far as `Request.Form` goes, same the method can be applied:

```
<%
    Dim key
    Dim serializedSession
    Dim serializedRequestForm
    Dim invokedNetDLL

    For Each key in Request.Form
        serializedRequestForm = key & "=" & Request.Form(key) & "&"
    Next

    'Trim last &
    serializedRequestForm = Left(serializedRequestForm, Len(serializedRequestForm) - 1)

    For Each key in Session
        serializedSession = key & "=" & Session(key) & "&"
    Next

    'Trim last &
    serializedSession = Left(serializedSession, Len(serializedSession) - 1)

    Set invokedNetDLL = CreateObject("MyNamespace.MyType")
    invokedNetDLL.MyMethod(serializedRequestForm, serializedSession)

%>
```

I haven't tested this code, but this is where I'd start.

Comment: I see... In other words, I can "stringify" the values I want to save.  I was hoping that the framework had something a bit more elegant available, but if I can't find anything else, I will certainly do something like this!

Comment: Maybe something like XML or JSON would be appropriate, given that it has conventions for escaping reserved characters and all.

Comment: I went with `QueryString`-style escaping (since I didn't know your .NET version), figuring it would be easy to decode, although you could certainly stringify it to XML or JSON (or a custom format). Also, this answer assumes that you can loop through a StateBag in Classic ASP, which I haven't tested. This should work unless you're keeping objects in Session, in which case you'll have to serialize those to primitives as well.